# Why does using an older kernel version help with wifi

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, kernel

I was wondering why when I use an older linux kernel version the Wifi drivers do not drop, but when I use the daily build or at least an up to date version they drop most frequently.

Comment: it takes time to flush out the bugs so tried and true code typically is more stable ...  perhaps the new drivers are making assumptions which help some hardware configurations yet hurt others ... developers do not have access to all hardware combinations so the code edge cases where not encountered

Comment: Good to know...

Answer (score 3):

Daily upgrades are generally not considered stable or hardened.  This is true of pretty much all software not just Ubuntu.  Clearly, software that has only seen minimal testing for 24-odd hours is going to be buggier than the same release that has been exhaustively tested.

Daily updates are for the early adopters who don't mind dealing with problems, bugs, things that used to work and now don't.  Whether getting on the daily update treadmill works for you is a personal decision.  However, once you adopt a daily upgrade methodology it is usually quite difficult to get off of it.

For those users who want and need a hardened, stable platform to work with, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is what they typically choose.  Updates are only added to the software update list after they have gone through regressive testing and have been tried out by a few early adopters.

The OP made a blanket statement inferring that wifi drivers in newer kernels do not work properly.  I don't believe this is true in most cases although depending on what wifi device the OP is using they may well have experienced instability after installing a daily upgrade now and then.

Comment: Good to know...helpful